# Tag wiki presentation box hides excerpt input box

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, tag-wiki

The input box for tag wiki excerpts is too wide and disappears under the “What are Tag Wikis” box. Please make it the same width as the full tag wiki input box.

(Observed under Firefox 3.0.6 and Chrome 10.0.648.133.)

[image]

Comment: Do you see this anywhere other than in Unix & Linux? I've not seen this neither here nor on Gaming (IE8/XP)

Comment: Looks fine on **Opera** which means all is well

Comment: @Grace: Oops, you're right, this is specific to U&L. Flagged for migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix will be in the next deployment.